# Unused Entity Issue: Expression result unused XCode 4

Tags: xcode, entity, xcode4

Have the following code and get the above error at the xs in the for statement initilization. Wasn't getting it in Xcode 3, just showed up when I installed Xcode 4 today. xs is a

```
int xs = 0;
for (xs; xs<3; xs++) {
        if ([colorLayoutArray objectAtIndex:xs] == [colorLayoutArray objectAtIndex:xs+1]){
            rowCorrectCount = rowCorrectCount +1;}
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: You're pasting a fragment, so we can't see variable declarations, especially what rowCorrectCount is and how it's used.

Answer (score 7):

Your "xs" in the first clause of the `for()` does nothing. The compiler is complaining at you probably didn't mean that. You meant one of the following:

```
for (int xs = 0; xs<3; xs++) {
        if ([colorLayoutArray objectAtIndex:xs] == [colorLayoutArray objectAtIndex:xs+1]){
            rowCorrectCount = rowCorrectCount +1;} }
```

or

```
int xs = 0;
for (; xs<3; xs++) {
        if ([colorLayoutArray objectAtIndex:xs] == [colorLayoutArray objectAtIndex:xs+1]){
            rowCorrectCount = rowCorrectCount +1;} }
```